# How to single-quote an argument in a macro?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, stringification

I would like to create a **C** pre-processor macro that will single-quote the argument. Just like the common used `#X`.

I want `Q(A)` to be expanded to `'A'`.

I am using gcc on Linux.

Does any one have an idea?

I know `#` double-quotes. I am looking for a similar mechanism for single-quoting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best you can do is

```
#define Q(x) ((#x)[0])
```

or

```
#define SINGLEQUOTED_A 'A'
#define SINGLEQUOTED_B 'B'
...
#define SINGLEQUOTED_z 'z'

#define Q(x) SINGLEQUOTED_##x
```

This only works for `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9` and `_` (and `$` for some compilers).

Comment: Oh, that second method is pure evil ;-)

Comment: `$` is not a valid character for an identifier, according to the C standard.  It may be accepted by some specific compilers, I suppose.

Comment: @Dale: Yes, GCC supports `$` as an identifier. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs

Comment: Dale: Well, the standard allows for implementation-defined characters beyond digits, ASCII letters and the underscore. But that's probably not very portable, then :)

Answer (score 7):

Actually, `#X` double quotes its argument, as you can see with the following code.

```
#define QQ(X) #X
char const * a = QQ(A);
```

Run this with `gcc -E` (to just see the preprocessor output) to see

```
# 1 "temp.c"
# 1 "<built-n>"
# 1 "<command line>"
# 1 "temp.c"

char * a = "A"
```

To single quote your argument (which in C means that it's a single character) use subscripting

```
#define Q(X) (QQ(X)[0])
char b = Q(B);
```

which will be transformed into

```
char b = ("B"[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

The best I can think of would be

```
#define Q(A) (#A[0])
```

but this isn't very pretty, admittedly.

Answer (score 1):

this generates conversions:

```
#python
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('n')):
    print "#define BOOST_PP_CHAR_%s '%s'" % (chr(i), chr(i))
```

and this is preprocessor part:

```
#ifndef BOOST_PP_CHAR_HPP
#define BOOST_PP_CHAR_HPP

#define BOOST_PP_CHAR(c) BOOST_PP_CHAR_ ## c
//  individual declarations    

#endif // BOOST_PP_CHAR_HPP
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried concatenation:

```
#define APOS           '
#define CHAR2(a,b,c)   a##b##c
#define CHAR1(a,b,c)   CHAR2(a,b,c)
#define CHAR(x)        CHAR1(APOS,x,APOS)
```

Unfortunately though, the preprocessor complains about an unterminated character. (and multicharacter if you have more than one character)
A way to just disable preprocessor errors: (there is no specific warning option for this)

```
-no-integrated-cpp -Xpreprocessor -w
```

Some compile-time optimization example with some other tricks:

```
#define id1_id       HELP
#define id2_id       OKAY

#define LIST(item,...) \
    item(id1, ##__VA_ARGS__)\
    item(id2, ##__VA_ARGS__)\
    item(id1, ##__VA_ARGS__)\

#define CODE(id,id2,...)    ((CHAR(id##_id) == CHAR(id2##_id)) ? 1 : 0) +
int main() { printf("%d\n", LIST(CODE,id1) 0); return 0; }
```

This returns "2", since there are two items that have id1.

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling with macros I found the solution.

```c
#define QUOTE_LITERAL() '
#define IN_QUOTES(x) QUOTE_LITERAL()x'
```

You will get warnings (for unterminated quotes) but can get rid of them with `-no-integrated-cpp -Xpreprocessor -w`. As mentioned by @darkfader