# C/C++ preprocessor single quote?

Tags: c-preprocessor, stringification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to single-quote an argument in a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072532/how-to-single-quote-an-argument-in-a-macro)

How can it do the following:

```
#define MACRO(X) ...
MACRO(a) // should give 'a'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be missing an easier way, but how about `#define MACRO(X) ((#X)[0])`.  The `#` stringtizes `X` and then `[0]` selects the first character.

Comment: hmm, unfortunately i need it for the meta programming, so string are not going to work

Comment: The answer to the duplicate of this question has a variation that would work.

Answer (score 3):

Seems it can't be done with the C preprocessor, at least the [gcc doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification)s states it bluntly:

> There is no way to convert a macro
>   argument into a character constant.

Answer (score -4):

Like this:

```
#include <string>

std::string Macro(const std::string& s)
{
  std::string ret = "'";
  ret += s;
  ret += "'";
  return ret;
}
```

### EDIT:

I posted this answer before it was revealed that this was needed for metaprogramming.  I don not know of a way to accomplish this for metaprogramming, but metaprogramming is not my forte.

Also, as for why I am effectively saying "don't use the preprocessor" in the first place, read the comments below.  But in short, I believe that almost everything that is commonly done using the preprocessor can and should be done using first-level constructs instead.  Using the preprocessor skirts the C++ type system and reduces safety.  Macros are difficult to debug, difficult to extend.  Extensively using macros will result in code that isn't familiar to the programmers who didn't create the macro, resulting in a kind of "secret language" only 1 person knows, decreasing maintainability of not only the macros, but the functions where they are used.

OK, I guess that wasn't so short, but there it is.

Comment: That doesn't use the preprocessor...

Comment: +1 for guiding the OP away from the preprocessor

Comment: -1 for completely not answering the question; I hate when I ask how to do X and the answer is "don't do X". The answer isn't even interchangeable with a preprocessor solution, you can't drop in a call to `Macro` where the user wanted to use `MACRO`, it wouldn't even build. It's like trying to replace `#define SUM(a, b) (a)+(b)` with `std::string sum(std::string a, std::string b) {return a + "+" + b;}`

Comment: -1 OP clearly says in another comment he needs this for meta programming

Comment: @marcog: Yeah, but that was 29 secs after John committed his question! `:)`

Comment: @Michael:  I'm of the opinion that *almost* everything that is commonly done with the preprocessor can & should be done not using the preprocessor.  Primarily because by using the preprocessor you lose all type information, lose much of your ability to debug, and gain nothing.  In my view, it's worth some effort to get that back, including refactoring the places where macros are used.  In many instances we might be able to engineer a non-preprocessor solution that can be a drop-in replacement for the preprocessor methods, but even when there's not, that's not going to stop me.

Comment: @John You may be right, but it's irrelevant. I'm of the opinion that C++ is vastly superior to PHP, but I don't answer PHP questions with "first switch to C++, then do this"

Comment: @Michael:  Apples and oranges.  But more importantly, one of the biggest problems I see in production code is programmers who certain things certain ways that are unsafe simply because that's what they know.  I don't know everything, but I do know a few things and I strive to learn more all the time.  I also try to teach others different, maybe "better" ways of doing things.  Sometimes I take some heat for this, and I definitely get a lot of downvotes on SO.  But if it gets some programmer thinking about "why does he hate the preprocessor?" then its worth it.

Comment: @Michael:  That's why I'm one of those who when asked "how do i do X"  I'll often answer "Dont do X."  *You* might know what you're doing, but somebody out there might stretch their knowledge a little, even if it isnt you

Comment: @John If you answer "you really shouldn't use the preprocessor for this, but if you need to then this is how" I'm totally fine with it, and I do that all the time. *Just* answering with "here's a solution that doesn't in any way use the preprocessor" is incredibly annoying for all the people that google this problem in the future and find an answer that very likely doesn't help them

Comment: @Michael: I see your point and agree, I should have stated that.  Hopefully these comments will clarify.  Fo what its worth, I usually do go in to some elaboration about why I said "dont do X".  Sometimes quite a bit.

Comment: @John Who's to say OP isn't doing this as a part as a fun project that has nothing to do with production code? There's a whole interesting field of metaprogramming which is mostly useless in real world applications, but still fun and interesting to dip ones feet into.

Comment: @Michael:  I've edited my post, let me know what you think if you have a moment.  @marcog: nobody.  this may well be the case.  In which case OP can ignore my advice, but I still would want to give the advice because others (like yourself) will be reading this.

Comment: -1.  I see nothing wrong with "You're doing this wrong, do it like this instead" answers.  However, even without the OP having mentioned template meta-programming, I do not consider the alternative proposal to be a legitimate proposal.  I would rather see any complaints about the OP's decision to use the preprocessor in a comment.